# How to manipulate character string being pointed to

Tags: c++, string, pointers

I'm sure this is an easy question for most but I'm having trouble trying to figure out why I can't manipulate this sting and better yet how I should go about doing it.  So for example we have:

```
char *str1="Hello World";
```

All I want to do is manipulate the string that is being pointed to by 'str1'.  For example, as shown below, I could output the string and see the original.  Then I could add a null character in there and shorten it.

```
cout << str1 << '\n';
str1[5] = '\0';
cout << str1;
```

I've also tried:

```
cout << str1 << '\n';
*(str1+4) = '\0';
cout << str1;
```

Either way I'm hoping to see something like this:

```
Hello World
Hello
```

The error I'm getting in both cases is when I try to alter the string.  I know it would be easier to just declare str1 as an array (`char str1[] = ....`) but I'm given the constraint of having to use the dreaded `char *`

Comment: You cannot modify a string literal. Fortunately the assignment to `char*` is deprecated in C++11.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

String literals are stored in read-only memory. You cannot modify them. In fact, in modern C++, attempting to initialise `str1` the way you did will give an error. It should be a `const char*`:

```
const char* str1 = "Hello World";
```

This makes it clear that you shouldn't be modifying the `char`s.

If you want a copy of the string that you can manipulate, you should make `str1` an array:

```
char str1[] = "Hello World";
```

When you initialise an array with a string literal, the characters are copied into the array.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  So, does this mean there is no way to save an editable copy of str1 if its been defined as a char* ?

Comment: @TrapLevel Sure, you'd have to copy the characters from the string literal to an array. That's what the second line I've given does automatically, but you can do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

So after all of the help I've received from you all I went with first determining the length of the strings, initializing an array of the same size+1, and then iterating through the original to save it into an array.  Then I was able to manipulate it as i pleased.

```
int someFunc(char *inpStr){
     int counter = 0;

     //Find the length of the input string
     while(inpStr[counter]!='\0'){counter++;}

     //Input initialize an array of same size
     char strArray[counter+1];

     //Copy whats in the char *   to the array and make sure it ends with null
     for(int i=0;i<=counter;i++){strArray[i]=*(inpStr+i);}
     strArray[counter]='\0';

     .....
return 0;
}
```

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score -1):

Why you cannot change the `str1` has been explained aptly by Joseph. But still if you want to modify it you can use something like this:

```
char *str = "hello";
char *ptr = new char[strlen(str)+1];
strcpy(ptr,str);
ptr[2] = 'd';
str = ptr;
```

I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: `ptr` will already be terminated by a null character after the call to `strcpy`.

Comment: Also if this approach is used, you must take care to use `delete`.

Comment: Most of the code could be replace by a single line calling strdup(), and it doesn't answer the question. -1

Comment: @dreamlax: you have to use `delete[]`, not `delete`.

Comment: @EJP: I have just stated one method. I am not saying that there are no other methods. And as TrapLevel has mentioned that he has constraint to deal with char* so i feel my post definitely modifies the incoming char*.

Comment: @SBP I like how you've done it however is there a lower level assignment I can use instead of strcpy?

Comment: @TrapLevel If you don't want to use strcpy use a for loop from 0 to strlen(str) instead of strcpy. Don't forget to append `ptr[strlen(str)] = '\0';` after for loop.

Comment: He didn't say anything about modifying the char*. He wants to *'alter the string',* and this code doesn't do it. Nothing does. It's read-only.